# Postgres: "Cannot call json_populate_recordset on an object" Error

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, recordset

I have a table with unpacked jsons in one column ("actionDetails"), sometimes with more than one json per row. For some strange reason, the query

```sql
    SELECT "idVisit" AS visit_id,
    t.* FROM dl.live_last_visits_details_pvk,
    json_populate_recordset(null::json_type, "actionDetails" :: JSON) as t
```

gives the exact results I want -- until I skip to the end of the results, when it closes the table and gives me `[22023] ERROR: cannot call json_populate_recordset on an object.`

Similarly, if I try to save this query to a table, I get the same error.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp AS (
    SELECT "idVisit" AS visit_id,
    t.* FROM dl.live_last_visits_details_pvk,
    json_populate_recordset(null::json_type, "actionDetails" :: JSON) as t
);
SELECT * FROM temp;
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this (perhaps some weird row value that's not a json?), and how I can resolve it? Not sure how to search for other kinds of objects that might be hidden in the column's values, and it's a very large table so I can't just sift through. The data I'm working with has many rows and changes frequently, so I need to write code that can handle oddities like this. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting this same error. In my case, when I had 2 or more rows in my version of `live_last_visits_details_pvk` everything worked fine. When I had exactly 1 row, PostgreSQL gets mad and throws this error. I don't have a clever solution for you (yet), but I hope that helps for now.

Comment: Input for json_populate_recordset should be a list of JSON objects. If you want to expand a single object, consider using json_populate_record.

Comment: Or wrap the single json in [] since recordset expects an array. Or as @Giri says, in use json_populate_record